# Setting up SSL on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, apache

I am fairly new to Mac and Apache httpd.

I need to set up SSL on my mac's inbuilt apache. I followed steps from [here](http://webdevstudios.com/2013/05/24/how-to-set-up-ssl-with-osx-mountain-lions-built-in-apache/) , but when I am trying to start httpd using this command

```
root# /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
```

I get error

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 501 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file /private/etc/apache2/other/cc7-local-httpd-ssl.conf: No such file or directory
```

and its true that cc7-local-httpd-ssl.conf file is not there. So, how do I get this file created or generated?

Comment: `cc7-local-httpd-ssl.conf` doesn't appear anywhere in that tutorial. Where'd it come from?

Comment: It is not a fresh mac install on this laptop, it might be having old config where this is coming from. Is there a way I can reset apache config to the defaults?

Comment: Presumably there's an `Include` sort of statement calling `cc7-local-httpd-ssl.conf`. Can't you just take it out?